# How to scale down the image for better quality on Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, image-scaling

Now I'm using the follow code to scale down the image downloaded from internet at runtime. But the result is not good enough.

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(srcBitmap, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "not good enough"?

Comment: did you able to resolved this, if so can you share the code...

Comment: Hi, Sam. Maybe you can try inSampleSize when using BitmapFactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result is not good enough for you, try dividing the size of the image by 2 until you reach the size you want.

Comment: Do you mean that use the same method with half width and height?