# How to scale the image loaded from sd card into image view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to scale image loaded from sd card into the image view .

**Problem** is whenever i load from sd card the image comes as full screen and i have set all the parameters fill_parent viewbounds scaletype etc. as per other questions.

What should be the way to do it ?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Frame"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Load1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame" />
```

this is my image view code can u tell me what to change so that image comes according to the imageview size

Comment: Can you also add the code to how you're putting it into an `ImageView`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `fitCenter` scaleType. In your layout definition, use the below attribute for your `ImageView`s

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Comment: Can you post the full layout code? What are the dimensions (width/height) of the image?

Comment: actually image is dynamicaly loaded from the gallery so i dont kno what the dimensions of the image are .

Comment: Try loading a small image, eg. a 100x100 image. I suspect you are loading very big images that end up filling the whole screen.

Comment: but thats the point i want any image size to be fit in the image view

Answer (score 0):

If the imageview is big and if you try to load a big image then the layout is doing what it is supposed to do.

So either give a fixed width/height to the ImageView instead of wrap_content or you have to scale the imagedown based on your Phones screen size.

Try this link : [How to scale down the image for better quality on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964939/how-to-scale-down-the-image-for-better-quality-on-android)
and some tips from here : [How to scale an Image in ImageView to keep the aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio)